# Looping through pandas DataFrame and having the output switch from a DataFrame to a Series between loops causes an error

Tags: python, pandas

I have vehicle information that I want to evaluate over several different time periods and I'm modifying different columns in the DataFrame as I move through the information.  I'm working with the current and previous time periods so I need to concat the two and work on them together.

The problem I'm having is when I use the 'time' column as a index in pandas and loop through the data the object that is returned is either a DataFrame or a Series depending on number of vehicles (or rows) in the time period.  This change in object type creates a error as I'm trying to use DataFrame methods on Series objects.

I created a small sample program that shows what I'm trying to do and the error that I'm receiving.  Note this is a sample and not the real code.  I have tried just simple querying the data by time period instead of using a index and that works but it is too slow for what I need to do.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : range(44, 51),
    'time' : [99,99,97,97,96,96,100],
    'spd' : [13,22,32,41,42,53,34],
})


df = df.set_index(['time'], drop = False)

st = True

for ind in df.index.unique():

    data = df.ix[ind]

    print data

    if st:
        old_data = data
        st = False
    else:
        c = pd.concat([data, old_data])

    #do some work here
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
  id  spd  time
time               
99    44   13    99
99    45   22    99
      id  spd  time
time               
97    46   32    97
97    47   41    97
      id  spd  time
time               
96    48   42    96
96    49   53    96
id       50
spd      34
time    100
Name: 100, dtype: int64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/m28050/Documents/Projects/fhwa/tca/v_2/code/pandas_ind.py", line 24, in <module>
    c = pd.concat([data, old_data])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 873, in concat
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 946, in get_result
    new_data = com._concat_compat([x.values for x in self.objs])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 1737, in _concat_compat
    return np.concatenate(to_concat, axis=axis)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

If anyone has the correct way to loop through the DataFrame and update the columns or can point out a different method to use, that would be great.

Thanks for your help.

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) could help here:

```
In [11]: spd_lt_40 = df1[df1.spd < 40]

In [12]: spd_lt_40_count = spd_lt_40.groupby('time')['id'].count()

In [13]: spd_lt_40_count
Out[13]:
time
97      1
99      2
100     1
dtype: int64
```

and then set this to a column in the original DataFrame:

```
In [14]: df1['spd_lt_40_count'] = spd_lt_40_count

In [15]: df1['spd_lt_40_count'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

In [16]: df1
Out[16]:
      id  spd  time  spd_lt_40_count
time
99    44   13    99                2
99    45   22    99                2
97    46   32    97                1
97    47   41    97                1
96    48   42    96                0
96    49   53    96                0
100   50   34   100                1
```

Comment: Thanks Andy,  This is just sample code and I'm doing a lot more then just getting aggregate stats like count.  I need to work will the whole subset of the data from the time period.

Comment: @user1204369 That's exactly what groupby allows you to do :) (the `.groupby('time')` bit) I recommend reading the [groupby docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)!

Comment: I modify the code to better show what I'm trying to do.  I need to combine to time periods to work on them and the size of the data sets fails because the single row data is converted to Series.

Comment: @user1204369 It's not really clear what you expect that to do, but using groupby ensures each groups is a DataFrame and then, for example, you can apply a function to that.

Comment: @user1204369 if you really wanted to do it manually you could use: `g = df1.groupy('time'); [g.get_group(x) for x in g.groups]`, but I recommend apply.